# Why we spread clothes for fast drying and how evaporation rate become faster then?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, evaporation

Why wrinkled cloth (not spread out) takes time to dry up

Look at diagram

[image]

Here, water molecule on surface of wrinkled area will also evaporate same as non wrinkled area (may be) ! So why it takes time to dry in non spreaded clothes.

**Why we have to spread clothes to dry after and how evaporation rate become faster then?**

Answer (score 5):

A given amount of air can only hold a finite amount of moisture (relative humidity).

Spreading the clothes out allows the air at the surface of the cloth to circulate better so that moisture-saturated air can be replaced by fresh dry air.

It's basically the same as why water evaporates faster in a container with no lid than a covered or partially covered container.

Answer (score 3):

Evaporation is a surface phenomenon, i.e., it takes place only on the surface molecules of the liquid. When the cloth is wrinkled, the surface area exposed to air is less than the situation when the cloth is spread out, so less water molecules escape to the air.

Answer (score 1):

When a cloth is wrinkled less area is exposed to air than the cloth that is not wrinkled so in this way ( as clothes that are more exposed to air dry up faster ) the cloth that is not wrinkled dry faster.